# Magento 1.9.1 model rewrite not executed

Tags: php, magento, debugging, model, url-rewriting

I've been trying for days now to get a rewritten model to function.
The code seems to be correct and the rewrite seems to work, but I can't see the logs, that I've put there for debugging purposes in the system.log.

I've tried several tutorials with all the same result.

Module WR_EPO is active and running. Even some installer-scripts for adding new columns in to my sql database are working fine.

Here's my code:

under **local/WR/EPO/etc/config.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
<modules>
    <WR_EPO>
        <version>1.0.0.1</version>
    </WR_EPO>
</modules>
<global>
    <models>
        <wr_epo>
            <class>WR_EPO_Model</class>
            <resourceModel>wr_epo_resource</resourceModel>
        </wr_epo>
        <wr_epo_resource>
            <class>WR_EPO_Model_Resource</class>
            <entities>
                <field>
                    <table>wr_epo_field</table>
                </field>
            </entities>
        </wr_epo_resource>

        <catalog>
            <rewrite>
                <product_option_type>WR_Catalog_Model_Product_Option_Type</product_option_type>
            </rewrite>
        </catalog>
        <wishlist>
            <rewrite>
                <item>WR_Wishlist_Model_Item</item>
            </rewrite>
        </wishlist>
    </models>

    <resources>
        <wr_epo_setup>
            <setup>
                <module>WR_EPO</module>
            </setup>
        </wr_epo_setup>
    </resources>

    <blocks>
        <adminhtml>
            <rewrite>
                <tag_edit>WR_Adminhtml_Block_Catalog_Product_Edit_Tab_Options</tag_edit>
            </rewrite>
        </adminhtml>
    </blocks>
</global>
</config>
```

the rewritten model under **local/WR/EPO/Catalog/Model/Product/Option/Type/text.php**:

```
<?php

class WR_Catalog_Model_Product_Option_Type_Text extends Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Option_Type_Text
{
/**
 * Validate user input for option
 *
 * @throws Mage_Core_Exception
 * @param array $values All product option values, i.e. array (option_id =>      mixed, option_id => mixed...)
 * @return Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Option_Type_Default
 */
public function validateUserValue($values)
{
    parent::validateUserValue($values);

    $option = $this->getOption();
    $value = trim($this->getUserValue());

    // Check requires option to have some value
    if (strlen($value) == 0 && $option->getIsRequire() && !$this->getSkipCheckRequiredOption()) {
        $this->setIsValid(false);
        Mage::throwException(Mage::helper('catalog')->__('Please specify the product\'s required option(s).'));
    }

    // Check maximal length limit
    $maxCharacters = $option->getMaxCharacters();
    $minValue = $option->getMinValue();
    $maxValue = $option->getMaxValue();
    if ($maxCharacters > 0 && Mage::helper('core/string')->strlen($value) > $maxCharacters) {
        Mage::log(
            "success maxChar in text.php",
            null,
            'WR_product-updates.log'
        );

        Mage::Log("success maxChar in text.php");
        if (isset($minValue) && isset($maxValue) && ($value < $minValue || $value > $maxValue)){
            $this->setIsValid(false);
            Mage::throwException(Mage::helper('catalog')->__('The value is not in range!!!'));
        }
        else{
            $this->setIsValid(false);
            Mage::throwException(Mage::helper('catalog')->__('The text is too long'));
        }
    }

    $this->setUserValue($value);
    return $this;
}
```

}

here I add 2 variables $minValue and $maxValue und afterwards I do the logging into system.log and additionally into a custom log file, but none of them appear, when I refresh the page (cache cleared beforehand).

**How can I fix/debug this? Why is the rewritten model not loaded instead of the core one?** From what I've read custom rewrites override core Models.

Help is very appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to change

```
<product_option_type>WR_Catalog_Model_Product_Option_Type</product_option_type>
```

to

```
<product_option_type_text>WR_EPO_Model_Product_Option_Type_Text</product_option_type_text>
```

put file to WR/EPO/Model/Product/Option/Type/Text.php
and change it class name from

```
class WR_Catalog_Model_Product_Option_Type_Text
```

to

```
class WR_EPO_Model_Product_Option_Type_Text
```

Comment: that worked. Thanks a lot, saved me tons of time! Plus I had to recompile from backend admin panel (log out and log in might help also)

Guess now I understand the way to do it.